# How can i transform my code to use multiprocessing(pool)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

```
for key in copy_reference_dataset:
    model_line_number = 0
    model_dictionary_elements_number = len(copy_reference_dataset[key])
    while model_line_number < model_dictionary_elements_number:


        compt = compt + 1
        if key in plus_min_dict:
            plus_min_dict[key].append(copy_reference_dataset[key][model_line_number])
        else:
            plus_min_dict[key] = [copy_reference_dataset[key][model_line_number]]

        validation_bool = False
        dictionary_elements_number = len(compared_to_dataset[key])
        ra = Rectangle(int(copy_reference_dataset[key][model_line_number][0]),
                       int(copy_reference_dataset[key][model_line_number][1]),
                       int(copy_reference_dataset[key][model_line_number][2]),
                       int(copy_reference_dataset[key][model_line_number][3]))
        model_line_number = model_line_number+1
        line_number = 0
        while line_number < dictionary_elements_number and \
                validation_bool is False:

            rb = Rectangle(int(copy_compared_to_dataset[key][line_number][0]),
                           int(copy_compared_to_dataset[key][line_number][1]),
                           int(copy_compared_to_dataset[key][line_number][2]),
                           int(copy_compared_to_dataset[key][line_number][3]))
            # print (rb)
            line_number = line_number + 1
            if area(ra, rb) >= (area(ra, ra)/2):
                # print ('ground truth area is' )
                plus_precision = plus_precision + 1
                validation_bool = True


            elif line_number == dictionary_elements_number:
                minus_precision = minus_precision + 1
```

My code is fully functional but pretty slow due to to the iterations and comparisons between 2 dictionaries where the values of each can surpass 300000 items, i've done some research about multiprocessing and realized that pool might be the best choice and running over 4 processors in parallel should be a good option, any hints on how to implement my first multiprocessing adjustments will be appreciated.